# Boarding pass not getting localization strings

Tags: passbook

I've been developing a boarding pass, everything went fine, but when I tried to internationalize it passbook is not loading strings. The pass works fine but is not getting localized strings. The odd thing is that it works fine on pass viewer, but on iphone and ipad it doesn't.

This is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "pass.json": "41ea636799de90475196cdf17f879653aa256e61",
    "icon.png": "6762942886bae7b11ad45f268faf082dcfe15ea7",
    "icon@2x.png": "d9de89daee9f8b24d6059018ab107b33e9efb744",
    "logo.png": "d63334e60ad0548b1bf07a0d6e133a8ccdb09f52",
    "logo@2x.png": "0ff3913da7f122a9f5d44ff3ad8c44e2fc06f24c",
    "en.lproj/pass.strings": "64c8e3def5193f82be5bea65ae10e2d0eb4ba3fa",
    "es.lproj/pass.strings": "beb344e5657994008bd1be5bda8c20347420b389"
}
```

this is part of the pass.json when I am trying to internationalize a string.

```
"headerFields": [
            {
                "key": "seat",
                "label": "seat_str",
                "value": "{seat}",
                "textAlignment": "PKTextAlignmentNatural"
            }
        ],
```

and this is en.lproj/pass.strings

```
"flight_str" = "FLIGHT";
"seat_str" = "SEAT";
"depart_str" = "DEPART";
"gate_str" = "GATE";
"plane_str" = "PLANE";
"passenger_str" = "PASSENGER";
```

Is it correct to include the en.lproj in the manifest file? Am I missing something in the pass.json file?

EDIT: Finally I found the problem, it was not on the pass itself, the issue was in the way I made the zip file. I was generating the zip file in .net and was adding pass.strings this way

```
var englishLocalizationEntry = archive.CreateEntry(@"en.lproj\pass.strings");
```

using windows file system path separator. For making it work correctly I had to change it to

```
var englishLocalizationEntry = archive.CreateEntry(@"en.lproj/pass.strings");
```

Comment: Your manifest seems te be ok. What are you seeing when loading the pass on the iPhone?

Comment: In the pass I am seeing "seat_str" instead of "SEAT", the same for all the other strings in pass.strings

Comment: This might sound stupid, but is the locale of your phone in the locales of the Passbook locales? And in your question you mention an iPad, but Passbook isn't available for iPad (yet). Are you using the regular Passbook application?

Comment: Yes, the locale is right. On iPad I am open it with the email, it seems it has a pass viewer. On iphone I am using passbook. Couldn't find the problem yet.

Comment: @EstebanElverdin - did you find solution for that? Seems like I have same problem now...

Comment: Hi Oleg, my problem was related to the path separator I was using when generating the zip file. Check the EDIT part of the question. Using the mac os path separator solved my problem.